# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo(android.view.InflateException:)

Tags: java, android, xml, google-maps-android-api-2

I want to import Google Api in my project to see google map but it shows error ( java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo)

I search  a lot related to this question but nothing foung enough related to my problem according to my code struture

Here is my Main Activity named as (GoogleMapLocat)

```
public class GoogleMapLocat extends AppCompatActivity {
//map data
private static final String TAG = "HomeActivity";
private static final int ERROR_DIALOG_REQUEST = 9001;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_google_map);

    //map data
    if (isServicesOK()) {
        init();
    }
}
//MAP DATA
public void init() {
    Button btnMap = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMap);
    btnMap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(GoogleMapLocat.this, MapActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}

public boolean isServicesOK() {
    Log.d(TAG, "isServicesOK: checking google services version");
    int available = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(GoogleMapLocat.this);
    if (available == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Google Play Services is Working");
        return true;
    } else if (GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isUserResolvableError(available)) {
        //an error occured but we can resolve it
        Log.d(TAG, "isServicesOK: an error occured but we can fix it");
        Dialog dialog = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorDialog(GoogleMapLocat.this, available, ERROR_DIALOG_REQUEST);
        dialog.show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "you can,t make map request", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
    return false;
}
}
```

Here is my Second Activity named as (MapActivity)

```
 public class MapActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback{
private static final String TAG = "MapActivity";

private static final String FINE_LOCATION = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;
private static final String COURSE_LOCATION = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION;
private static final int LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1234;

//vars
private Boolean mLocationPermissionsGranted = false;
private GoogleMap mMap;




@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

    getLocationPermission();
}
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Map is Ready", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "onMapReady: map is ready");
    mMap = googleMap;
}

private void initMap(){
    Log.d(TAG, "initMap: initializing map");
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

    mapFragment.getMapAsync(MapActivity.this);
}

private void getLocationPermission(){
    Log.d(TAG, "getLocationPermission: getting location permissions");
    String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION};

    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(),
            FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(),
                COURSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            mLocationPermissionsGranted = true;
        }else{
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    permissions,
                    LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }else{
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                permissions,
                LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult: called.");
    mLocationPermissionsGranted = false;

    switch(requestCode){
        case LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:{
            if(grantResults.length > 0){
                for(int i = 0; i < grantResults.length; i++){
                    if(grantResults[i] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                        mLocationPermissionsGranted = false;
                        Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult: permission failed");
                        return;
                    }
                }
                Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult: permission granted");
                mLocationPermissionsGranted = true;
                //initialize our map
                initMap();
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Here is mapactivity.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<fragment xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    tools:context=".MapsActivity"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is GoogleMapLocat.xml file:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".GoogleMapLocat">
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Map"
    android:id="@+id/btnMap"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is my Stack Trace:

```
E/UncaughtException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.e_agriculture10/com.example.e_agriculture10.MapActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2243)
  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
  at com.example.e_agriculture10.MapActivity.onCreate(MapActivity.java:37)
   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.e_agriculture10/com.example.e_agriculture10.MapActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment 
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
```

According to this line of error

```
   at com.example.e_agriculture10.MapActivity.onCreate(MapActivity.java:37)
```

Here is the Affected area

```
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
```

because when i click on (MapActivity.java:37) the cursor blinks on the start of this line( setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);)

According to this line of error

```
 Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
```

here is the affected block of code (as i think this is the key area related to my error)

```
 <fragment xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    tools:context=".MapsActivity"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

What,s wrong in this fragment which leads to inflate exception?

Comment: which version of com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps are you using?

Comment: here is the block of code  to get google play services version( android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" ) @GabrieleMariotti

Comment: Get the version in your build.gradle file

Comment: This is the block of code to get version in build.gradle( implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.4.0')@GabrieleMariotti

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using androidx libraries, you have to use a [`SupportMapFragment`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment) [migrated](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#june_17_2019) from Android Support Libraries to AndroidX Libraries.

In you case use this version or later.

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0
```

If you check the doc it extends `androidx.fragment.app.Fragment`.

Comment: Thumbs up for you man!!! My error has gone and program excuted perfectly but why still map is not showing in my project?can you guide me please?

Comment: You should open a new question. In this way the community can help you